# Toggle menu item visibility when Edittext gain and lose focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-menu, onfocus

I need to show to `Toolbar` menu item when `EditText` gains focus and hide it when `EditText` lose focus.

I try to implement using `setOnFocusChangeListener` on `EditText` like below:

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           if (hasFocus) {
              sendMenuItem.setVisible(true);
           } else {
              sendMenuItem.setVisible(false);
           }
      }
});
```

but menu item is show and hide continuously as `onFocusChange()` is calling multiple times.

onFocusChange() is calling multiple times .

It is strange Logcat shows me following warning:

> requestLayout() improperly called by
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView

is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by calling multiple times?

Comment: yes it is calling continuously

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `TextWatcher` to know if anything is entered in `EditText` or not. And then show/hide your `MenuItem`.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
          sendMenuItem.setVisible(true);
       } else {
          sendMenuItem.setVisible(false);
       }
    }
});
```